# Java-Firebase connection not working

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I have been trying to connect a dynamic web project on eclipse ee to firebase. I have uploaded all the required dependencies (from a maven project).

Here is the code I have used directly from the firebase documentation on Java.

```
public class FirebaseUpdater {

public static void main(String[] args){
    FileInputStream serviceAccount;
    try {
        serviceAccount = new 
                FileInputStream("C:/Users/Asus/workspace/school-dy2"
                        + "/schoolbackup_service.json");

        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                .setDatabaseUrl("https://schoolbackup-f2429.firebaseio.com/")
                .build();

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

        // As an admin, the app has access to read and write all data, 
        //regardless of Security Rules
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference();
        DatabaseReference attendance = ref.child("Attendance1");

        attendance.setValueAsync("Debarred");
        System.out.println(attendance.toString());

        attendance.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

          public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              System.out.println("Datasnapshot Received");
              Object document = dataSnapshot.getValue();
              System.out.println(dataSnapshot.getKey());
          }

          public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
          }
        });

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

I have also used the correct procedure for getting the service account key (Firebase Console->Users and Permissions->Service Accounts->Generate New Private Key)

The database security rules are also public (Not that it should be a problem to begin with since I have the service account key):

```
{
"rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
    }
}
```

The project compiles successfully and the internet connectivity is not a problem.

I have checked the workspace url as well. It correctly takes me to the database on a browser.

However despite all this, my project does not seem to connect to firebase and update values.

Could someone tell me what could be the possible problems? I am at a dead end here.

Please note that I am using eclipse ee (dynamic web project) and I have directly imported the maven dependencies for com.google.firebase (groupID), firebase-admin (artifactID), 6.2.0 (version).

Could it be that I cannot use the maven dependencies for a dynamic web project? Is the service account key method the problem? Is there any possible workaround for this?

EDIT:
I tried printing the GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount) to see what is wrong. This is what I got:

```
    ServiceAccountCredentials{clientId=109785559732337174527, clientEmail=firebase-adminsdk-0into@schoolbackup-f2429.iam.gserviceaccount.com, privateKeyId=5512743509a43e1371cf88ec3feba4007abe4bf1, transportFactoryClassName=com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Utils$DefaultHttpTransportFactory, tokenServerUri=https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token, scopes=[], serviceAccountUser=null}
```

serviceAccountUser is null. Could that be a problem? If yes, how do I solve it.

Comment: No, as i said the project compiled successfully.

Comment: I'm confused. The code you're showing just looks like a standalone java app, not a j2ee project or any sort of web app.

Comment: Let me rephrase that: Are you getting any errors when you run it?

Comment: +Andre Oh sorry! No I get absolutely no errors on running it

Comment: +Doug Yes it is a standalone project. I however started it as a dynamic web project hence I mentioned it

Comment: If you want to mention someone in a comment you need to put @ instead of +, like this: @DougStevenson read the above comment. (No need to do that for the person asking the question because they get notified for every comment under their question (like this))

Comment: How are you executing this program?  What output does it generate?  Have you tried putting lots of print statements in it to see how it's getting executed?  Have you tried step-through debugging?

Comment: @DougStevenson There are a few things I could mention. I tried to print a few variables of the FirebaseOptions I am using, like databaseurl, projectID etc. It is giving 'null' for projectID. Could that be the problem? Although I don't think so because nowhere in the documentation has it been mentioned that I have to set the projectID

Comment: Also 1 more thing I checked recently. I tried printing the account credentials from the 'GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount)'. I'll just add the output

Comment: Most likely your `main()` method is exiting before any of the event handlers could fire. Add some wait logic to the end: `Thread.sleep(5000)` and see what happens.